# [__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a weird problem. My project keeps breaking at "//CRASHES" and I get this error code.

> [__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:

It crashes right after if statement where str is equal to passedstring.

The void method is called from   `[self findMyArray:words];`
Words is a mutable array that has "fruits" which is also a mutable array. 
I added fruits to words by

`[words addObjectsFromArray:fruits];`

---

```
 - (void) findMyArray:(id)array {

    NSMutableArray*stoploop;


    if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [array isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    for (NSMutableArray *temp in array) {
        for (NSString *str in temp) {

            if ([str isEqualToString:PassedString]) { 
                //CRASHES
                stoploop=temp;



            }
        }
    }
}


    if (fruits==stoploop) {
       NSLog(@"true");
    } 
}
```

Comment: log before the crash str and PassedString and you will get the answer immediately

Comment: does `fruits` array have String element or Array element?

Comment: This won't solve the problem but you don't need to check for `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` in your `if`. `NSMutableArray` is a kind of `NSArray` so this check can be omitted. i.e. `if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])` is sufficient

Comment: Could you check that `str` is really a `NSString`, or `passedString` is?

Comment: fruits array has strings.

Comment: Could you log `array`?

Answer (score 1):

as the `fruits` array have string elements, on adding `[words addObjectsFromArray:fruits];` each element in `fruits` array will be added to `words` as elements of `words` array. So the element in `words` array will also be Strings.

Solutions:
Sol 1. If you want element of `words` should be array, use `[words addObject:fruits];` instead of `[words addObjectsFromArray:fruits];` so the rest code will work.

otherwise,
Sol 2. If you are not using Sol 1, then change the array iteration logic as follows,

```
for (NSString *str in array) {

   if ([str isEqualToString:PassedString]) { 
        //CRASHES
        stoploop=temp;
    }
}
```